# Mock urlilb+json in Python

Tags: python, mocking

looking for a way to correctly mock this piece of code:

```
import json
from urllib import urlopen

a_url = "http://blabla"
my_response= urlopen(a_url)
a_dict = json.loads(my_response.read())
```

It reads from an URL, then the response uses json.loads to store everything in a dict. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`urlopen` should return a mock object where `.read()` returns a string containing JSON, e.g. `'{"a": "b"}'`.

Then throw it all away and use `requests`.